# How to open hdf file in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04

I have faced serious problem to open hdf file but there shows nc file not associated solve this problem and give suggestion.

Comment: https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/HDF5/HDF5  "The HDF5 Technology suite includes tools and applications for managing, manipulating, viewing, and analyzing data in the HDF5 format." leads to https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/HDF5/HDF5+Command-line+Tools and https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/HDF5/HDF5+Tools+by+Category

Answer (score 6):

Simply install HDFView from the repository with

```
sudo apt-get install hdfview
```

and use it top open some h5-file:

[image: HDFView 2.9 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS]

Comment: Nothing against the OP here but before installing, note that most Ubuntu distributions come with version 2.x. This version in more that one occasion showed me empty files (which were not in fact empty). Furthermore, version 3.1.1 which is the latest at the time of running is only available for centos which to be fair on Ubuntu, however, you should register in order to download! But there is a link somehwere hidden in their webpage. Just avoid it IMO...

Answer (score 4):

You can use command line tools

```
apt install hdf5-tools

h5dump file.h5
```

Answer (score 3):

### Python modules

- [`netcdf4`](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/netCDF4/index.html) (also provides some nice CLI tools (`ncinfo`, `nccopy`, ...))
- [`h5py`](https://www.h5py.org/)
- [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/)

### GUI Tools

- [Panoply](https://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/panoply/) from NASA can visualize HDF5 data very well.
- [HDFView](https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/HDFVIEW/HDFView)

Find more tools from the [hdfgroup website](https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/HDF5/Tools).